# How does the mod two map work in Cohomology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

In the following proposition from Geiges book *Introduction to Contact Topology* he refers to "even" elements of $H^2(M;\mathbb{Z})$. What I am confused about is this: If I have a contact manifold of dimension n+1 and I know that $H^n(M;\mathbb{Z}) = H^n(M;\mathbb{Z}_2) = \mathbb{Z_2}$, can I conclude that the only possible Euler class for the contact structure, as an n-plane bundle, is zero in light of the below information?

[image: prop 4.3.2 Geiges]

It seems to me that this is the same as asking about the relationship between $H^k(M;\mathbb{Z}) / 2$ and $H^k(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)$

Comment: In what context did you encounter such a use of the term "even"?  Most often I would think "even cohomology classes" refers to cohomology classes in even _degrees_ (so it is $k$ that would be even).

Comment: well one of my professors uses this terminology. He says things like "only even torsion in H^1" and I think from context that he means it's even if it's zero when you reduce it mod two.

Comment: I would assume "only even torsion" means every torsion element has order that is a power of 2.  (That is, "even" is referring to the order of torsion, not to the elements themselves.)

Comment: Hm okay that's fine maybe I should edit my question... 
But what I am really wondering about is how the mod two map works then.

Comment: By the way this related question illustrates the context pretty well: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3579079/is-there-a-higher-dimensional-analogue-to-this-proposition

So in this question, they say "even element" in H^2 not just "every element" in H^2

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question very well, but aren't you kind of asking about the link between $H^k(M;\mathbb{Z})/2$ and $H^k(M;\mathbb{Z}/2)$?

Comment: yes! That's exactly right.

Comment: But in a precise "element by element" way. Does that make sense? I think one can get information about that relationship in terms of isomorphisms from the universal coefficient theorem. 

but that's not exactly what I'm asking. If I literally have an integral class and then reduce it mod two, what happens to it?

Comment: Your "context" is wrong: the $w_6$ in the "context" is *not* the $6$th Stiefel-Whitney class of (the tangent bundle to ) $M$, but is $w_6$ of your $6$-plane bundle.  And if $M = \mathbb{R}P^3$, then $H^2(M) = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, but there is a rank $2$-bundle over $M$ whose Euler class is the non-trivial element of $H^2(M)$ - pull back the tautological bundle over $\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ along a map which is non-trivial on $H^2$ (which exists because $\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ is a $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$.)

Comment: Sorry you're right I was getting really mixed up. 

I was thinking about a situation where the tangent bundle splits as a line bundle plus another piece.